# Only one instance of a Swiffy conversion works on page with multiple conversions?

Tags: html

Placing multiple swiffy conversions on the same page seems to conflict, only the first one shows up. Is there an area of code, possibly instance names, that I can change on each one so that multiple conversions can appear on the same page?

Here's a link to the page I'm talking about: http://www.ufonies.com/fansmobi.html

The animation in the header works fine, there should be another small animation under the "Space Golf" image but it just appears as a blank space, the conversion code there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too with a slider - each slide was a swiffy animation and every time I used two or more animations, swiffy threw an error.
I got around this by using iframe containers for slides instead of divs - this way each animation had its own namespace for variables and scripts.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually

The swiffyobject should be renamed to anything ex. swiffyobject2, swiffyobject3 and so on.

See in this example the container is renamed to container2 so is the Element id 
And then i call swiffyobject2 instead of swiffyobject. that way we can use as much instances of swiffyobjects as we want.

```
<div id="swiffycontainer2" style="width: 190px; height: 195px">
    </div>
    <script>

      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer2'),
                                   swiffyobject2);

      stage.start();
    </script>
```

I like to create separate js files for every object and just call one instance of

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.2/runtime.js"></script>
```

but that's just a personal taste. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Roobns! I've found this works well if each swiffyobject is unique and not from the same document or if you're working with AS2 conversions.  If working with AS3, and the document class is reused in multiple files, you'll need to go into the swiffyobjects of each result, located "internedStrings" and find the item that matches your AS3 Document class name.  Add an enumerator to that to make it unique for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make new instance.

Example:

```
var swiffyIntroSlide = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('intro-slide'), introSlide);
swiffyIntroSlide.start();

var swiffyBanquePopulaire = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('top-banner'), banquePopulaire);
swiffyBanquePopulaire.start();
```

Notes:
introSlide & banquePopulaire are variables of swiffy objects.